# Spina CMS routes set default landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing, spina-cms

I have Rails app that uses [Spina CMS](https://www.spinacms.com/),

I want the landing page `\` to be one of the pages in admin.

for ex. `localhost:3000\home` is my `localhost:3000`

currently getting 404 setting `root :to => 'pages#home'`

Seems `root :to ...` is getting overriden by Spina routes
[image]

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  match '(*any)', to: redirect(subdomain: ''), via: :all, constraints: {subdomain: 'www'}

  mount Spina::Engine => '/'

  root :to => 'pages#home' # => not working...

  get '/*id' => 'pages#show', as: "page", controller: 'pages', constraints: lambda { |request|
    !(request.env['PATH_INFO'].starts_with?('/rails/') || request.env['PATH_INFO'].starts_with?("/#{Spina.config.backend_path}") || request.env['PATH_INFO'].starts_with?('/attachments/'))
   }
end
```

Comment: Would you give us more info about the route file

Answer (score 0):

In the route page replace   `root :to => 'pages#home'` to `root 'pages#home'`
and add

```
 resources :pages
```

Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Hi @nourza it will look for home controller?

Comment: still getting 404 for localhost:3000  :(

Comment: Check this link https://www.storyblok.com/tp/ruby-on-rails-cms